# Can't Dual Boot into Windows 7 after Intalling Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, 15.04, unetbootin

Usually before I load into an OS, I get the option menu to select Windows 7 or Recovery mode(I have thinkpadx220);

Then I used Unetbootin, which appeared as the third option. After installing Ubuntu 15.04, I don't see this option anymore it just goes straight into Ubuntu without the option for Win7, Recovery, or even Unetbootin.

I can still view all my files from Ubuntu though like Program Files and Windows folders.

I already tried this
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

I made my log at 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/11791943/

It didn't fix it.

Comment: You converted your sda1 from the Windows boot partition with essential Windows boot files to Linux swap. You do not have to have the separate Windows boot partition, but must move or reinstall the Windows boot files into your main working install. And to repair Windows boot flag must be on the NTFS primary  partition you want to install boot files into. You may be able to undo the change to swap as that has no format. And if you have lots of RAM you may not have used swap, so it may still contain your boot files. Do not reformat it, but use Disks to change type to 07 (NTFS) and add boot flag.

Answer (score 0):

I think the grub is creating issues. Reinstall grub.

Try this:

Edit the GRUB Configuration File, open the `/etc/default/grub` file for editing in a standard text editor.

If you want to use a graphical text editor, open a terminal — or press Alt+F2 — and run the following command:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the Bootable Drive of Windows 7(Of the same Version of Your Windows 7 You Are using) And Repair The PC

Comment: Windows 7 preinstalled on my laptop, I don't have a Windows 7 cd. Plus thinkpadx220 doesn't have a CD

Comment: If u have ISO File of Windows 7 than u can also try With Bootable USB Drive Of Same OS Version of Win 7 You Was Using